# Website blocking Selenium : is there a way to bypass?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This webpage opens fine manually, but directly goes to a "maintenance" error message when using Selenium !

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/")
```

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour ?

Comment: See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver

Comment: i read the article (and some others before it) and it seems quite complicated to implement for me : maybe there are some python lines "ready-to-use" to add to a script ?   ;-)

Comment: What makes you feel _Website blocking Selenium_? What is the _"maintenance" error message_?

Comment: "Winamax est actuellement en maintenance" although it is not (confirmed by the company itself) : when trying to access the exact same page manually, it shows the list of the bets

Comment: I have no problem to open page with Selenium and I don't see any "maintenance" error message. Maybe it was no error but simply they have short break for changes on page. Maybe it will work next day.

Comment: 2 days in a row working fine manually and not with selenium : maybe it's a combination of IP detection + selenium detection ?

Comment: if you think that it can be IP detection + selenium detection then search how to use Proxy servers with Selenium (but mostly free Proxy servers don't work good so you may have to pay for servers) and Search also question "how to detect Selenium" - as I know Selenium inject  JavaScript code to control browser and some portals can recognize variables to recognize this code and people change variables to resolve this problem. But you will have to search more details in Google or Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the websites checks your `user-agent`. Maybe you can change that.

Otherwise, I would recommend using Auto-It to do the job.

You could also try loading in your personal Chrome profile into Selenium.

Comment: i tried changing the chromedriver like mentionned in several pages but it didn't change a thing

Comment: also changed the user-agent, with no luck

Comment: i spent 3 weeks to write my script in python/selenium, finding the correct xpaths, etc. i'm unfortunately pretty much sure i cannot do as well with auto-it

Comment: Could you please share the chromedriver version used and the version of chrome browser as well?

Comment: @jeremoquai I am encountering the excatly same issue :( It's quite furstrating after my 3 months of hardwork writing the script and compiling it. Could you find any possible solution? I also posted in stackoverflow, but no luck till now

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear why you felt *website blocking [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)*. However I was able to access the website following the solution below:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')

  driver.get('https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section#above-content a[href='/paris-sportifs']")))
  print(driver.page_source)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <html class="app-desktop js flexbox canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths pointerevents cssremunit" lang="fr" style=""><!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]--><!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><!--<![endif]--><head>
      <title>Paris Sportifs - Parier en ligne avec Winamax</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
      <meta name="verify-v1" content="divGwlYLgkmoS558zISY8BYg1KLLvQLFmRf0CmPJ1kc=">
      <meta name="google-site-verification" content="DB-aVdWJ00FHClrX_fsXFGgZzaYUKGVcvY7uSfOkXsw">
      <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Winamax">
      <meta property="og:description" content="Agréé par l’Arjel – Pariez sur le sport sur Winamax! Faites un premier dépôt et votre premier pari sera remboursé si il est perdant.">
      <meta property="og:image" content="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/img/content/betting/ParisSportif_Facebook.jpg?v=20150401">
      <meta property="fb:admins" content="519584907">
      <meta property="og:site_name" content="Winamax.fr">
      <meta property="og:type" content="game">
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
      <meta name="twitter:site" content="@WinamaxSport">
      <meta name="twitter:title" content="Paris Sportifs - Parier en ligne avec Winamax">
      <meta name="twitter:description" content="Agréé par l’Arjel – Pariez sur le sport sur Winamax! Faites un premier dépôt et votre premier pari sera remboursé si il est perdant.">
      <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/img/content/betting/ParisSportif_Facebook_twitter.jpg?v=20150401">
      <meta name="twitter:domain" content="winamax.fr">
      <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/">
      <link rel="stylesheet" id="normalize" href="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/style/v2/normalize.css?v=20191219-1" type="text/css" media="all">
      <link rel="stylesheet" id="reset" href="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/style/v2/reset.css?v=20191219-1" type="text/css" media="all">
      <link rel="stylesheet" id="fontawesome" href="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/style/v2/fontawesome.min.css?v=20191219-1" type="text/css" media="all">
      <link rel="stylesheet" id="magnific-popup" href="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/style/v2/magnific-popup.css?v=20191219-1" type="text/css" media="all">
      <link rel="stylesheet" id="spritesheet" href="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/style/v2/spritesheet.css?v=20191219-1" type="text/css" media="all">
      <link rel="stylesheet" id="common" href="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/style/v2/common.css?v=20191219-1" type="text/css" media="all">
      <link rel="stylesheet" id="fancybox" href="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/style/v2/jquery.fancybox.css?v=20191219-1" type="text/css" media="all">
      <link rel="stylesheet" id="doubleslider" href="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/style/v2/doubleslider.css?v=20191219-1" type="text/css" media="all">
      <link rel="stylesheet" id="source-sans-pro" href="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/style/fonts/SourceSansPro/source-sans-pro.css?v=20191219-1" type="text/css" media="all">
      <link rel="icon" href="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/img/style/v2/favicon.ico" type="image/png">
      <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/img/style/v2/20170721_touch_icon_winamax.png">
      <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/">
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/">
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.winamax.fr/en/sports-betting/">
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://www.winamax.fr/de/sportwetten/">
      <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/script/swfobject.js?v=20191219-1"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/script/v2/betting-helpers.js?v=20191219-1"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/script/numeral.js?v=20191219-1"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/script/numeral.languages.js?v=20191219-1"></script>
      <script src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/script/v2/lib/modernizr.custom.js?v=20191219-1"></script>
      <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <script src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/script/v2/lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js?v=20191219-1"></script>
      <script src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/script/v2/lib/selectivizr-min.js?v=20191219-1"></script>
      <![endif]-->
  <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/script/messages/messages_fr.js?v=20191219-1"></script>
      <script>
      var $siteLanguage = 'FR';
      var $siteLanguagePath = '';
      var $siteLicense = 'FR';
      </script>
      <style data-styled-components=""></style><script charset="utf-8" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/betting/client/1.55.1/main.30da6bcf4d935f4ad03c.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/betting/client/1.55.1/main.6dcf45fd436abb91aedd.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/betting/client/1.55.1/main.1812cb976eb7abff1666.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/betting/client/1.55.1/main.fbe533b04c719597d791.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquery" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/script/v2/lib/jquery-1.12.4.min.js?v=20191219-1"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="swipe" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/script/v2/lib/swipe.js?v=20191219-1"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="touch" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/script/v2/lib/jquery.touch.js?v=20191219-1"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="magnific" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/script/v2/lib/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js?v=20191219-1"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="fancybox" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/script/v2/lib/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=20191219-1"></script><style id="detectElementResize" type="text/css">@keyframes resizeanim { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 0; } } .resize-triggers { animation: 1ms resizeanim; visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; } .resize-triggers, .resize-triggers > div, .contract-trigger:before { content: " "; display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; } .resize-triggers > div { background: #eee; overflow: auto; } .contract-trigger:before { width: 200%; height: 200%; }</style><style type="text/css">.fancybox-margin{margin-right:17px;}</style><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="script/v2/common" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/script/v2/common.js?v=20191219-1"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="script/v2/mobile" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/script/v2/mobile.js?v=20191219-1"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="script/v2/gallery" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/script/v2/gallery.js?v=20191219-1"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="script/v2/doubleslider" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/script/v2/doubleslider.js?v=20191219-1"></script></head>
      <body class="lang-fr license-fr">
      <div id="wrap-menu-overlay"></div>
  <!-- Facebook -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>$fbLocalized = 'fr_FR';</script>
  <div id="doc">
      <div id="inner-wrap"><div style="cursor: pointer; background: url(&quot;https://static.winamax.fr/img/style/v2/common/avertissement.png?v=2&quot;) center center no-repeat rgb(0, 0, 0); height: 60px; z-index: 112; display: block;"></div>
  <script>
        var arjelBannerImgPath = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "https://static.winamax.fr/img/style/v2/common/avertissement.png?v=2" : "https://static.winamax.fr/img/style/v2/common/avertissement-alt.png";
        function setupArjelBanner() {
          var ref = document.getElementById("inner-wrap");
          if (ref) {
            var banner = document.createElement("div");
            banner.style.cursor = "pointer";
            banner.style.background = "url('" + arjelBannerImgPath + "') no-repeat center center #000";
            banner.style.height = "60px";
            banner.style.zIndex = Math.floor(50 + Math.random() * 100);

            function goArjelInfos() {
          window.open("https://www.winamax.fr/CLIC/PREVENTION/JIS_HOME/www.joueurs-info-service.fr");
            }

            function WidthChange(mq) {
          if (mq.matches) {
            var arjelBannerImgPath = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "https://static.winamax.fr/img/style/v2/common/avertissement-mobile.png?v=2" : "https://static.winamax.fr/img/style/v2/common/avertissement-alt-mobile.png";
            banner.style.background = "url('" + arjelBannerImgPath + "') no-repeat center center #000";
            banner.style.backgroundSize = "100% auto";
          } else {
            banner.style.display = "block";
          }
            }

            banner.addEventListener("click", goArjelInfos, false);
            ref.insertBefore(banner, ref.firstChild);

            if (matchMedia) {
          var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)");
          mq.addListener(WidthChange);
          WidthChange(mq);
            }
          }
        }
        setupArjelBanner();
      </script>
  <div class="top-notif-wrapper"><div class="notification top-notif medium cookie-consent">
      <i class="icon-warning-sign"></i>
      <p><span>En poursuivant votre navigation sur ce site, vous acceptez l’utilisation de Cookies afin de réaliser des statistiques de visites et vous proposer des promotions adaptées. <a href="/a-propos_conditions-generales-d-utilisation_s-opposer-aux-cookies?cookie-consent=0" target="_blank">S’y opposer</a> - <a href="/a-propos_conditions-generales-d-utilisation_plus-d--information-sur-les-cookies?cookie-consent=0" target="_blank">Plus d’informations sur les cookies</a></span></p>
  <a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().hide(); return false"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></div>
  </div><header id="masthead">
      <div class="container">
      <a href="/" id="logo">
          <img src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/img/style/v2/common/logo.png" alt="Winamax">
          <img class="hover" src="https://operator-front-static-cdn.winamax.fr/img/style/v2/common/logo-highlight.png" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="content">
  <div id="login-toggle" class="toggle">
      <a href="/account/login.php?redir=/paris-sportifs/">
        <svg id="user-icon" viewBox="0 0 32 24">
          <path d="M10.3,13.9c0,0-7.1-0.1-9.8,5.3v4.7h9.8h9.8v-4.7C17.5,13.8,10.3,13.9,10.3,13.9z"></path>
          <ellipse cx="10.3" cy="6.4" rx="4.9" ry="6.2"></ellipse>
        </svg>
      </a>
        </div>
  <div id="login-container" class="expandable">
      <a href="/account/login.php?redir=/paris-sportifs/" id="login-link">Se connecter</a>
      <a href="/account/create.php" id="signup-button" class="button">S'inscrire</a>
      <div id="login-popup">
      <form id="login-form" method="post" action="/paris-sportifs/" autocomplete="off">
          <p class="field">
          <label>Adresse email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="loginbox_email" placeholder="vous@exemple.com" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" value="">
          </p>
          <p class="field">
          <label>Mot de passe</label>
          <input type="password" id="loginbox_password" name="password" placeholder="" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off">
          <a class="forgot-password" href="/account/lost_password.php">Mot de passe oublié ?</a>
          </p>
          <p class="field birthdate">
          <label for="day-input">Date de naissance</label>
          <input type="text" id="loginbox_birthday" name="birth_day" autocomplete="off" placeholder="JJ" tabindex="3" pattern="[0-9]*" size="2" maxlength="2" value="">
          <input type="text" id="loginbox_birthmonth" name="birth_month" autocomplete="off" placeholder="MM" tabindex="4" pattern="[0-9]*" size="2" maxlength="2" value="">
          <input type="text" id="loginbox_birthyear" name="birth_year" autocomplete="off" placeholder="AAAA" tabindex="5" pattern="[0-9]*" size="4" maxlength="4" value="">
          </p>
  <button type="submit" id="login-button" name="submitlogin" class="secondary-button" tabindex="6"><i class="icon-lock"></i>Connexion</button>
      </form>
      <div id="no-account">
          <a href="/account/create.php"><span>Pas encore de compte ?</span> Inscrivez-vous gratuitement</a>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div id="pin-popup">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="search" class="expandable" style="height:28px">
  </div>
  <div id="nav-toggle" class="toggle">
        <svg id="list-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <rect x="6" y="17" width="18" height="3"></rect>
      <rect x="6" y="10.5" width="18" height="3"></rect>
      <rect x="6" y="4" width="18" height="3"></rect>
      <rect x="0" y="4" width="3" height="3"></rect>
      <rect x="0" y="10.5" width="3" height="3"></rect>
      <rect x="0" y="17" width="3" height="3"></rect>
        </svg>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  <nav id="main-nav" class="">
      <ul class="main-nav-list">
  <li class="">
      <a href="/jouer-au-poker">JOUER AU POKER</a>
  </li>
  <li class="focus">
      <a href="/paris-sportifs">PARIS SPORTIFS</a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
      <a href="/paris-sportifs-grilles">GRILLES</a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
      <a href="/jde/contests">JEU DE L’ENTRAINEUR</a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
      <a href="/paris-sportifs_promos_accueil">PROMOS</a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
      <a href="/l-espace-vip_introduction">VIP</a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
      <a href="/paris-sportifs_actus">ACTUS</a>
  </li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  </header>
  <section id="above-content">
      <nav id="secondary-nav" class="container">
      <div id="section-title">
      <a href="/paris-sportifs">Paris Sportifs</a>
      </div>
      <ul>
  <li><a href="/paris-sportifs" ng-class="menuClass('sport')" data-nav="home" class="betting-top-nav selected">À la Une</a></li>
  <li><a href="/paris-sportifs/live" ng-class="menuClass('live')" data-nav="live" class="betting-top-nav">LIVE</a></li>
  <li><a href="/paris-sportifs/multiplex" ng-class="menuClass('multiplex')" data-nav="multiplex" class="betting-top-nav">Multiplex</a></li>
  <li><a href="/paris-sportifs/winamax-tv" ng-class="menuClass('winamaxtv')" data-nav="winamax-tv" class="betting-top-nav">Winamax TV</a></li>
  <li><a href="/paris-sportifs/calendar" ng-class="menuClass('calendar')" data-nav="calendar" class="betting-top-nav">Calendrier</a></li>
  <li><a href="/paris-sportifs/history" ng-class="menuClass('history')" data-nav="history" class="betting-top-nav">Mes paris</a></li>
  <li><a href="/paris-sportifs-betradar-stats" class="">Stats</a></li>
  <li><a href="/paris-sportifs_scores-en-direct" class="">Résultats</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
  </section>
  ```

Comment: i copied/pasted your code and i still have "Winamax est actuellement en maintenance" !